# multiple times escaping "&" in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing one sql query as below :-

```
select a, b, c
from table_name
where b in (
'some string & some string'
,'some other string & some other string'
)
```

Things I have tried :-

1. Tried using `SET DEFINE OFF`. It seemed to work fine but its use is restricted to sql developer only, which is not my requirement. As i need to export this query to other tool for creating report.
2. Tried using `chr(38)` like

```
'some string'|| chr(38) ||'some string'
,'some other string'|| chr(38) ||'some other string'
```

But it works fine when I use it one time. Using `chr(38)` multiple times is throwing error.

Any leads over here is aprreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I disagree!! You can use CHR(38) as many time as you want in your string.

Comment: `Using chr(38) multiple times is throwing error.` --- Which error it is throwing?

Comment: SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE 'a' || CHR(38) || 'a' IN ('a' || CHR(38) || 'a' , 'y' || CHR(38) || 'y');

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chr(38)` as many times as you want. In your example, I can see that spaces are not managed properly. There is space before and after `&`.

**Your actual string**: `'some string & some string'`

**Your string with concatenation**: `'some string'|| chr(38) ||'some string'` --> `'some string&some string'` --> You can see that spaces before and after `&` is missing in your concatenated string.

so this space must be there after concatenation. Following will help you

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dual
  3  where 'some string '|| chr(38) ||' some string' in (
  4  'some string '|| chr(38) ||' some string' -- see the space before and after concatanation
  5  ,'some other string ' || chr(38) ||' some other string'
  6  );

D
-
X

SQL>
```